# using magento apis for ecommerce website

Tags: magento, e-commerce

I am a beginner in magento and am working on creating a website using magento. I have noticed that magento has a good number of apis that expose all of the functionality that I would need to create an ecommerce website. So, I would like to use magento's apis to fetch data, but develop the UI separately without any dependencies on magento. I have found a lot of references that develop the website via magento theming, but not those where the UI is developed in a separate MVC and uses magento purely as service layer. Are there any problems/issues in my approach?

Edit: I have gained a lot of clarity on db performance issue in apis and how external caching can alleviate the issue, but I still don't understand the underwhelming use of magento as a service layer (i.e. fueling the website by using magento's apis), are they any other gotchas?

Comment: well the main issue is gonna be you not be able to find any references to that topic :)

Comment: I tried a lot, but it seems that it is not a preferred approach hence the lack of articles around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how we overcame slowness in Magento APIs:

1. Created a Web service provider in J2EE, Spring MVC that acts as a proxy between Magento and end users.
2. J2EE Web service provider exposes pretty much all the APIs that Magento has but also supports JSON with REST along with SOAP & RPC.
3. J2EE Web service provider uses a document based database (MongoDB) to store a snapshot of product catalog in MongoDB.
4. J2EE Web service provider uses native MongoDB caching to serve data fast without running any expensive SQL queries.
5. To avoid dirty caching issues we created a hook in Magento Admin to push data into MongoDB whenever data changes in Magento.

This might sound like overkill to some but we have been able to achieve pretty high throughput without any slowness.

Comment: thanks, interesting to hear that you used mongodb. Did you face any "session expiration" issues as mentioned by JMC.

Comment: No we haven't encountered any "session expiration" error from Magento even while under simulated heavy load from multiple Jmeter nodes.

Comment: I have also found shopping cart apis such as adding to cart to be quite slow compared to what can be done in home grown platform. I notice that you mentioned you used mongodb for product attributes, but what about these other apis/functions?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention earlier that we aren't using Magento's order management. We are storing shopping cart states and orders directly in MongoDB itself.

Comment: that begs the question why use magento at all, since you seem to be doing most of the stuff outside of it?

Comment: Correct and we asked this question many times to ourselves and response was to mainly utilize their catalog admin dashboard and avoid doing it all over again by ourselves.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17437/discussion-between-142857-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 2):

The Magento APIs are slow, you would encounter serious performance issues trying to run a  site off of it.

Due to the complex nature of the EAV model, you may find it difficult to manage products through the API alone.

Are there any particular concerns you have about using Magento's own frontend? It is daunting at first but once you understand the layout system it's actually very powerful and customisable.

Comment: Thanks, what makes magento apis slower than vs using magento's frontend? My concern is the feedback that I received from a few people who have worked on magento wrt ability to control the UI elements precisely. As a complete outsider, I like the idea of developing the UI with complete control and use a set of apis to power the functionality of catalogue, search, cart, promotions, checkout etc. That just seems to be a more natural way of development.

Comment: It does take a little skill, but overall it is possible to design any UI you want for magneto.

Comment: If you're using the APIs then you have the overhead of using web requests instead of direct model access. Even when using the API models directly I find them slower than going straight to the core. I presume that they do a lot of validation that isn't done by the core models.

Comment: @142857: Magento APIs are really slow because they aren't making any use of the various caching that are utilized by their front end UI. Magento's database's object model is pretty complex (same as Ofbiz) and fetching a single product page worth of information gets translated to multiple multi-join queries and in the absence of any caching these queries tend to get slow under constant load.

Comment: @anubhava, thanks for your answer. So, if I use a caching layer such as memcached to cache the results of apis esp product fetch, then it should be fine?

Comment: Yes if you use caching layer then it would behave better however you need build a mechanism to avoid dirty cache and clear cached content as and when product details are changed via their dashboard. I can post details about my implementation if you like.

Comment: @anubhava, would love to know more details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Technically it is possible to run a site only through the API.

The issue you might face is a practical one, instead of spending your time trying to learn all the API calls, you can learn how to implement your current UI in Magento.

The advantage to this approach is that you will also better understand how Magento works internally, thus allowing you to leverage it's functionality for your unique business needs.

Another issue is that when using API's you have a little less control over how things are processed / calculated, vs when working in Magento itself there is a lot of control over specifics.

Answer (score 1):

I regularly see "session expiration" issues when accessing Magento's API, through both SOAP and XMLRPC. All my calls require exception handling to avoid halting execution. I imagine that alone would create a nightmare when building everything on top of the API.

The best answer you're going to get is to [Load Test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_testing) the API before you start coding. Log the tests extensively and look for errors. If you see errors on a normal basis that should answer your question. Even if you find documentation that says it's okay to do what you're trying, you're still going to have to tune the API to work properly under the load required to run the store.

It will be good to know what you're up against before sinking hours into development.

Comment: can you please explain a little more. I tried playing a bit with the apis and didn't face any such issue.

Comment: Sometimes when two simultaneous calls are made to the API, even when the calls originate from different API webusers, magento returns "session expiration" to one of the two calls. Session expiration acts like a fatal error to the expired script and it halts execution if proper handling isn't in place. It could just be my configuration, but my hardware and php configuration are more than adequate to handle the load. Don't be surprised if you run into this issue when trying to call the API hundreds to thousands of times per minute as would be required to run an entire store.